# AWS Lambda accessing file

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a certificate file named `development.p12` under folder `Certificates`. Its build action is set to `Content`. This allows reading the file using the path `"Certificates\\development.p12"` when running locally. When publishing to AWS Lambda this does not work though - the file can not be found using the same path.

At which path can I access the file with build action `Content` under AWS Lambda?

Comment: How are you making the `development.p12` file available to the AWS Lambda function?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am deploying the certificate using `build action: Content`. What this does is copy the certificate to the build folder near the other DLLs.

Comment: So, it appears that you are [Deploying an AWS Lambda Project with the .NET Core CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-cli-publish.html). Is that correct? The trick will be to figure out where files end up once the project is deployed to Lambda.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It's correct except the CLI part. We are deploying using the AWS extension from inside VS (which might use CLI underneath but who knows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the path "Certificates/development.p12" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda functions run under Amazon Linux, therefore any Windows like path will not work. Not only that, the **only** directory you have **write** access to from within a Lambda function is ***/tmp***

Do keep in mind that you have a limit of 512MB on this folder.

You can find more about AWS Lambda Execution Environment [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) and more about Lambda Limits [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)

Comment: `/tmp` is the only *writable* directory, but the extracted contents of the zip file are readable from the read-only directory `/var/task`, which also happens to be the initial current working directory... and system folders like `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are readable and contain all the usual system components and other things (e.g. `/usr/bin/perl` is quite usable from a forked shell with pipes)... at least, this is the case for some Lambda runtime environments (Node.js, Python).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I meant to say it but I must admit I forgot to mention it was the only writable directory. Anyways, the OP apparently wants to save something and then read it afterwards, so I did not worry too much about it. Thank you for your input!

Comment: My assumption was that it was a pre-existing file that was believed to have been included in the deployment and was expected to be readable, but was not found.  I don't know what "its build action is set to Content" means but assumed it was related to building the deployment package.  I may be off track.

Comment: I think you're correct. After reflecting over it a little bit I also think the file should already be deployed with the app. However, what I said still stands: any Windows path like will not work since Lambdas run under Amazon Linux. Do we agree there? 
I think you're on track! Maybe I was the one a little bit off track :)

Comment: You very well may be correct about the path, unless c# has built-in magic/portability accommodations for path separators.  The specific error might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# then "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory" will work. This pulls the files from /var/task folder in lambda.